# Convert multidimensional array to array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have this data:

```
input = [ [ 'abc', '1.1' ], [ 'abc', '1.2' ], [ 'xyz', '3.14' ] ]
```

I would like output like the following:

```
[ { 'abc' => [ '1.1', '1.2' ] }, { 'xyz' => '3.14' } ]
```

Is it possible to achieve this in one chained expression?

Comment: Yes, probably. What did you try? What was the result? _(this smells like homework or an interview question...)_ See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) specifically: _Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first._

Comment: I tried a bit but it was too late. Instead of going to bed I made a post on SO..
 
Also as below noticed I made a typo in start question (missed "[]" around '3.14') 

I am sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
input = [['abc', '1.1'], ['abc','1.2'], ['xyz', '3.14']]

output = input.each_with_object(Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = [] }) { |(k, v), h| h[k] << v }
output # => {"abc"=>["1.1", "1.2"], "xyz"=>["3.14"]}
```

An alternate, which isn't as straightforward is:

```
input.group_by{ |k,v| k }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)] }.to_h # => {"abc"=>["1.1", "1.2"], "xyz"=>["3.14"]}
```

Your output structure

```
output: [{'abc' => ['1.1', '1.2']}, {'xyz' => '3.14'}]
```

is a very poor way to use a hash. Instead, you should have one hash, with multiple elements, since you're combining the like-key's values into one key.

---

If you *REALLY* need the output that way, as some seem to think, then simply append a `map` to the returned value:

```
input.each_with_object(Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = [] }) { |(k, v), h| h[k] << v }.map{ |k, v| {k => v} } 
# => [{"abc"=>["1.1", "1.2"]}, {"xyz"=>["3.14"]}]
```

Comment: This does not return the output OP specified.

Comment: The output specified isn't a good practice and the OP needs to learn that.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, why bother answering the OP's question when you can answer an easier question and tell them they asked the wrong question...

Comment: One of the things we do on Stack Overflow is correct bad programming practices. Let the OP decide which is the appropriate thing to do.

Comment: Then remove your answer. You clearly did not answer the OPs question correctly. Stop trying to be a hero. Answer the question, let them know how a good format should look and move on. If you're not answering the original question, then this is not an answer and should be removed.

Comment: I agree whole-heartedly, @theTinMan, when actual poor practices are in evidence, but you have no idea what OP's use case is. Perhaps instead of saying, "Your question is bad and you don't want what you think you want, here's what you want instead," you could ask, "Hey, it seems odd that you want an array of hashes when a plain hash seems like a pretty natural fit. Is there a reason for that?" That way you don't sacrifice an opportunity to give guidance on best practices but also don't insult OP's intelligence.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I could think of:

```
input.group_by {|x| x[0]}.each_pair.map { |k, v| {k => (a=v.map(&:last)).count > 1 ? a : a[0]} }
```

Comment: This does not return the output OP specified.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is like this:

```
def convert_marray_to_hash(input)
  hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
  output = []

  input.each { |array| hash[array[0]] << array[1] }
  hash.keys.each { |key| output << { key => hash[key] } }      

  output
end
```

There are many ways to do it, but that way presents itself nicely and is readable.

Comment: This does not return the output OP specified.

Comment: Not quite, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well:

```
input = [ [ 'abc', '1.1' ], [ 'abc','1.2' ], [ 'xyz', '3.14' ] ]

input.each_with_object({}) do |(key, val), hsh|
  hsh[key] = val and next unless hsh.key?(key)
  hsh[key] = [ *hsh[key], val ]
end
.map {|key, val| { key => val } }
# => [ { "abc" => [ "1.1", "1.2" ] },
#      { "xyz" => "3.14" }
#    ]
```

If you omit the final `map` you end up with a hash, which seems like a more natural result, but this matches the output specified, at least.

Comment: This returns the output specified, but I suspect the OP would be better off with the output everyone else gives.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's why I pointed out that omitting the last line would return a hash. ;)

Comment: Jordan, I was referring to "xyz" => ["3.14"] versus "xyz" => "3.14". Sorry for the confusion. (I now see there was some discussion of that elsewhere.)